# How can I see mining success log?

Tags: mining

I run geth on testnet with --mine option. Seems mining is running. What log will be showed if mining success?

```
INFO [07-16|04:02:56] Starting mining operation 
INFO [07-16|04:02:56] Commit new mining work                   number=1308362 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=260.17µs
INFO [07-16|04:02:57] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=43 percentage=6 elapsed=11.383s
INFO [07-16|04:02:59] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=43 percentage=7 elapsed=12.867s
```

Comment: After DAG generation process, did you try making any transaction? If yes and you are not seeing any mining logs on geth console then try running miner.start()

Comment: Thanks. I didn't make a transaction yet. I will try to make a tx and check about miner.start()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After DAG generation process, Try making any transaction. Even after that if you are not seeing any mining logs on geth console then try running -

```
miner.start()
```

Mining logs may look like this  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUR9E.png